# Unintended extra bar and stacking in Matplotlib Bar Graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote the following function that can plot a bar charts from an array of floats that I pass in. It's producing strange results for the second case I illustrate in the following examples. What is causing the extra stuff being drawn?

```
def create_plot(title, data, xlabels=None, colors=None):
    '''Plot the data as a bar chart'''
    if colors:
        bars = pyplot.bar(range(1, len(data) + 1), data, align='center', color=colors)
    else:
        pyplot.bar(range(1, len(data) + 1), data, align='center')

    pyplot.xlabel('X-axis')
    if xlabels:
        pyplot.xticks(range(1, len(data) + 1), xlabels)
    else:
        pyplot.xticks(range(1, len(data) + 1))
    pyplot.ylabel(r'Y-axis')
    pyplot.title(title)
    pyplot.axis([0, len(data) + 1, 0, max(data) + max(data) * 0.2])
    pyplot.grid(True)

    pyplot.show()
    pyplot.savefig('%s.png' % title)
```

When I pass in the data, it produces the following graph. Which is perfectly as I intended it to do [image]
However when I pass in an array with the min, average, and max of the data set, it stacks extra stuff on the bars and there's a 4th bar on the right. I've made it print back the length of the returned bar list and the len was 3.

```
average = sum(data) / len(data)
stats = [min(data), average(data), max(data)]
create_plot("Title2", stats, ["minimum", "average", "maximum"], ["red", "green", "blue"])
```

[image]

On the red bar labelled "minimum", there's some extra blue bar on top, even though I didn't specify stacking. On the left, there's an extra half a bar. What's causing this?

Comment: Looks like the new plot is being put on the same axis as your previous one, I generally do `fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()` at the start of each individual plot to make sure I'm using a separate figure, then plot on that axis using e.g. `ax.bar()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marius is correct in that the bar you're seeing is because you're plotting over your previous plot. Simply adding a `pyplot.figure()` to the beginning of your plotting function will solve this; when the figure and/or axis isn't specified, most pyplot functions will operate on the current figure, which, if you've just created a new one, will be the new one.

Alternatively, if you *want* to use the same figure (eg, if you want to keep the same window in some backends), you can instead use `pyplot.cla()` to clear the axis, or `plyplot.clf()` to clear the entire figure.